# wordpress only output current date and the date in the database is different

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress, in the database there's a table name "tblvessel" that store the vessel schedule, the column "date" in the table contain the date value of each vessel.

The code down here only display the same date. 
Ex: I have 10 vessels and they got different date
and the code will display the same date as today's date.

database:

Name     | date

---

vessel A | 2017-07-20

vessel B | 2017-07-19

vessel C | 2017-07-18

vessel D | 2017-07-17

vessel E | 2017-07-16

---

display:

Name     | date

---

vessel A | 25/July/2017

vessel B | 25/July/2017

vessel C | 25/July/2017

vessel D | 25/July/2017

vessel E | 25/July/2017

```
<?php
$q = $second_db->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM tblvessel WHERE status = '1' AND type=$type AND public='1'" );
    foreach ( $q as $print )   {
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="ves-td"><?php echo $print->vessel;?></td>
        <td class="ves-td"><?php echo $print->flag;?></td>
        <td class="ves-td"><?php echo $print->origin;?></td>
        <td class="ves-td"><?php echo $print->destination;?></td>
        <td class="ves-td"><?php echo $print->expected;?></td>               
        <td class="ves-td"><?php echo date_format(date_create($row['date']), 'd/m/Y' ); ?> <?php echo $print->eta_etd; ?></td>
        <td class="ves-td"><?php echo $print->remark;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: mistake in $row['date'], please add $print->date;

Comment: @ShitalMarakana , thanks a lotsssssssssssssssss!!!! need to delete the ";" at the end though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$row['date'] is  returning null causing

```
(date_create($row['date']), 'd/m/Y' );
```

to return current date.
use:

```
$print->date
```

instead of $row['date']

Answer (score 0):

use date function

```
<?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($print['date']));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your display code for date says

```
<?php echo date_format(date_create($row['date']), 'd/m/Y' ); ?> 
<?php echo $print->eta_etd; ?>.
```

Firstly, what is `$row`? I don't see that defined anywhere, shouldn't it be `$print`?

Secondly, the date format you specify does not match what you say the output is! `25/July/2017` is not `d/m/Y`, since that would surely display `25/07/2017`?

So it looks like the date is the same because you keep accessing the same `$row` var, but it also looks like the `$print->eta_etd` is blank? Maybe `var_dump($print);` to see what's happening with that.

Hope this helps!